# Why the email with sparkPost go in spam?

Tags: node.js, sparkpost

I use SparkPost to send email but The email that I send it goes in spam.
The send email that I use is :

```
sandbox@sparkpostbox.com
```

maybe it's for this that the email goes in spam.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SparkPost sandbox is available for everyone to send 50 emails. It is mainly to make sure your account is functioning properly. Because of this, the sparkpostbox.com domain doesn't will probably never have a great sending reputation. You should setup and verify a sending domain for better inbox placement.

Comment: I have domain-ed, but still goes to spam

Comment: i already  setup and verify a sending domain but still goes to spam